# UINavigation bar disappearing in iPhone 4 (iOS 7.1.2)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uinavigationbar

It may be a small issue but I'm not getting where & what is wrong.
When I am running on simulator from iPhone 4s to 6+ it's working fine.

[image]

But when I am running on iPhone 4 (iOS 7.1.2) the red colored navigation bar disappears.

Here is my code

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
  [[UINavigationBar appearance]setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
 }
```

For more details

1) I'm entering into this screen using show segue from previous view.

2) This screen I have made it in storyboard.(I checked constraints too but all constraints are right) I didn't have given any navigation bar in storyboard. Also I have not hidden navigation bar in controller through programatically.

3) I also tried

```
//    UINavigationBar *navbar = [[UINavigationBar   alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
//    [navbar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
//    [self.view addSubview:navbar];
```

in both viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear but it's not working.

Can anyone please help me out?

After some suggestions i tried updating following code in viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear (with deployment target 7.1)

```
 if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
 {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
 }


    UINavigationBar *navbar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 55)];
    [navbar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

[self.view addSubview:navbar];

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 19, 20)];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapBackBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIBarButtonItem *backBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButton;
```

Facing same issue.

Comment: What is your iOS deployment target?

Comment: And one thing you can check now is translucent property. Since in iOS7 all controller translucent property value is YES, try set navigation bar's translucent property to NO and see if that can solve your issue.

Comment: my deployment target is 7.0 and i tried adding   self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO; in both viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear. Still not working.

Comment: Try putting this in your viewDidLoad: `if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;`

Comment: Nope! what will be the reason ? its happening in only device. In all simulators its working fine why it is so?

Comment: So please update your question regarding your latest comment.

Comment: question is updated, let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88480/discussion-between-shrikant-kankatti-and-sanitlee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some more time, i got solution  [image]

Whenever there is Show segue from one VC to another like above. Then UINavigation bar code

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
 // Override point for customization after application launch.
 [[UINavigationBar appearance]setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
 }
```

is not working for iOS 7.1 (in my case it was happening for Buy voucher second view controller).

So i just removed segue and going through next screen using

```
- (IBAction)didTapOnNext:(id)sender
{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
BuyVaucherSecondViewController *bvs = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"buyVaucherSecond"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:bvs animated:YES];
}
```

Then it worked for me & navigation bar is showing for iOS 7.1. :)